# Editing Chrome Extensions(Adblock) Code so that it does not open a new tab when installed

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome-extension

I am using selenium with python to open chrome and the Adblock gets installed every time I load it.
In addition to the tab that I want to use a "Thank you for Installing adblock" tab opens which is very annoying. To close the tab I tried this

```
chld = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to.window(chld)
driver.close
```

Closing the driver like this does not allow me to continue on the main tab as I get this error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window: target window already closed
```

So to deal with this I thought maybe I can edit the adblock crx files to not open the new tab but I don't know how and what changes I can make.
Here is [folder](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KlkASMCqwk_5-QZTZ8o-J7iwhgk8a93v?usp=sharing) for the adblock files that can be edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following patch to focus on the current tab after closing the "Adblock" tab:

```
chld = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to.window(chld)
driver.close

current_tab=driver.window_handles[0]
driver.switch_to.window(current_tab)
driver.get("https://www.yahoo.com")
time.sleep(2)
```

Let me know if this worked for you

Comment: That's great! Can you mark this post as answered please?